# how to add static block to magento product description

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, php

I want to modify the product pages in my Magento store (I'm using version 1.4.2) so that a particular static block is appended to the description. I'm using the easytab system right now, but many of my customers can't find the information that I want to present to them when it's in a tab other than the default tab.

How can I adjust the template so that the static block I want (it's the same for every product) appears on product pages after the description block?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to edit the file /template/catalog/product/view.phtml in your current theme. Find this line:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('description') ?>
```

Then below it add this:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('extrainformation')->toHtml(); ?>
```

The *'extrainformation'* part being the identifier of the static block you created.